# parse iCalendar date using c#

Tags: c#, .net, icalendar

Is there a direct way to parse an iCalendar date to .net using c#?
An iCalendar date looks like this:

```
2009-08-11T10:00+05:0000
```

I need to parse it to display it in a friendly format... thanks

Comment: found a semi answer:
using 

DateTime..::.Parse Method (String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles) 

with style as None a,d format provider as culturecurrent, but i still have a problem, the icalendar date above raises an exception, apparently it does not allow the last two zeros! i dont know what the last two zeros are for, but is there a way around this?

Comment: See my answer below, I had assumed that date represented 10:00 + 5 hours i.e. 15:00 (3:00pm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string strDate = "2009-08-11T10:00+05:0000";
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
dtfi.FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmzzz";

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(c.Substring(0, c.Length-2), dtfi);
```

zzz is for time zone, but is only recognized when expressed like this: +xx:xx.
I tested with your example, removing the last 2 0's then parsing with a custom DateTimeFormatInfo works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime.Parse()` to parse everything before the +. I do not know the iCalendar format specification but I assume after the + is the hours/minutes to add to the date before the +. So you could then use `AddHours()` and `AddMinutes()` to add the required bits to the DateTime returned by `DateTime.Parse()`.

This requires a bit of string parsing but with a bit of regex you should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a standard format string, but you know the exact format, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` and specify [a custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmzzz00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The 'zzz' specifier represents the hours and minutes offset from UTC, and the two concluding zeros are just literals to match format with which you're dealing.